# Bochner's Theorem for Periodic Functions

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

It's fairly straightforward to prove the following, which *seem* like special cases of Bochner's Theorem for periodic functions, but don't quite match the statements of Bochner's Theorem that I've seen, because they give a *specific* form for the nonnegative measure. (To my knowledge Bochner's just states that *there exists* a certain nonnegative measure.) Are the following stated and proven somewhere in the literature? I've Googled around, but haven't found anything.

1. Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an even function with integer period $s$. Then $f$ is positive semidefinite if and only if the discrete Fourier transform $c_0,\ldots,c_{s-1}$ of the sequence $f(0),\ldots,f(s-1)$ satisfies $c_k\geq 0$ for all $k$.
2. Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be an even function with period $s$ whose Fourier series converge on $[0,s]$. Then $f$ is positive semidefinite if and only if its Fourier series coefficients are all nonnegative.

In (2) above I refer to the exponential form of the Fourier series, i.e. the Fourier series coefficients $c_k$ satisfy

$$ f(x) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} c_k \exp(\imath 2 \pi k x / s). $$